# Уникальный некластеризованный индекс и повторяющиеся значения NULL

Tags: sql-server

Вобщем-то сабж. Необходимо создать колонку, в которой могут быть только неповторяющиеся значения или неограниченное количество NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом вам поможет *фильтрованный индекс*:

```
create unique index IX_TableName_Column on TableName (Column) where Column is not NULL
```

Comment: Хвала небесам!!

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko Ждал таймаута стековерфлоата, не волнуйтесь.